# Unable to draw multiple charts using Xlsxwriter by calling a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I am using Xlsxwriter to draw multiple charts in a single worksheet. The problem is for different sets of data when I am calling the function to add a chart, it is overwriting the previous xlsx and drawing only the latest chart. Here is my main program:

```
  # Write some data to add to plot on the chart.
 data = [
            [51, 62, 33, 14, 95],
            [52, 64, 36, 18, 10],
            [53, 66, 39, 12, 15],
           ]
 meas_num = 1
 tc.power_chart_excel(data,meas_num)
```

and here is the function:

```
 def power_chart_excel(self, data, meas_num):

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/Amitra/chart.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


    # Create a new Chart object.
    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
    ---- #Other chart commands

    #Writing data to different columns for different charts
    worksheet.write_column(wr_col_num_1 + '1', data[0])
    worksheet.write_column(wr_col_num_2 + '1', data[1])
    worksheet.write_column(wr_col_num_3 + '1', data[2])
    #worksheet.write_column(wr_col_num_4 + '1', data[3])
    #worksheet.write_column(wr_col_num_5 + '1', data[4])



    # Configure the chart. In simplest case we add one or more data series.
    #chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5'})
    chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$' + wr_col_num_1 +  '$1:$' + wr_col_num_1 +  '$5'})
    chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$' + wr_col_num_2 +  '$1:$' + wr_col_num_2 +  '$5'})
    chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$' + wr_col_num_3 +  '$1:$' + wr_col_num_3 +  '$5'})
    chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$' + wr_col_num_4 +  '$1:$' + wr_col_num_4 +  '$5'})
    chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$' + wr_col_num_5 +  '$1:$' + wr_col_num_5 +  '$5'})


    worksheet.insert_chart(chart_position, chart)

    workbook.close()
```

How can I call this function multiple times to draw multiple charts in the same sheet without deleting the previous one? I have tested that if I do not call a function and open the chart once and close once then multiple charts are introduced. But I can not figure out how can I do the same thing using this function.

Answer (score 3):

Your workbook object represents a new Excel file. Xlsxwriter cannot append to an existing xlsx file. Therefore, you should keep your workbook open and add new charts in the same workbook. Your code could look like this:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/Amitra/chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for d in my_data: # or a similar loop depending on your program
    tc.power_chart_excel(worksheet, d, meas_num)

def power_chart_excel(self, worksheet, data, meas_num):
    # Create a new Chart object.
    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
    # rest of the code goes here
    worksheet.insert_chart(chart_position, chart)
```

Comment: I tried some similar code, but it seems that producing multiple worksheets with charts within a class structure isn't completely working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442534/dynamically-produced-xlsxwriter-charts-in-python-not-referencing