# Dynamically produced XLSXWriter charts in python - not referencing

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm using the below class I've written to try and dynamically create a single Excel file with several worksheets where there is a printed dataframe and a column chart in each worksheet.

Interacton with the code (seen below) should function where you initiate a workbook:

```
test = Workbook('Test Workbook')
```

And then, you can add as many charts as you want:

```
test.add_chart(df, 'Df Title', 1)
test.add_chart(df2, 'Df2 Title', 1)
```

And then you produce the workbook:

```
test.produce()
```

Input dataframes have headers. First column is text categories, subsequent columns (of varying number) are data in the form of decimals, that are to be graphed as percents.

THE ISSUE: The code works fairly well, and seems to produce all of the worksheets separately with charts, BUT some of the charts appear as "not referenced", meaning that when I click on a bar in the column chart, it does not highlight the source data. Some of the charts produced with the code, DO reference appropriately, so I am not sure where the issue is, and there is not an obvious trend.

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

class Workbook:

def __init__(self, workbook_name):
    self.workbook_name = workbook_name

    self.workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(str(self.workbook_name) + '.xlsx')

    self.letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P']

def produce(self):
    self.workbook.close()
    print 'Created ' + str(self.workbook_name) + '.xlsx'

def print_frame(self, worksheet, dataframe, df_width, start_data_index):

    col_as_lists = []
    col_names = list(dataframe.columns.values)    

    # loops through columns in df and converts to list
    for n in range(0, df_width):
        col_n = dataframe[col_names[n]].tolist()

        # checks to see if column has numbers, if so -> convert to float!
        if n < start_data_index:
            col_n.insert(0, col_names[n])

        elif self.is_number(col_n[0]):
            convert = col_n[0:]
            convert = [float(x) for x in convert]
            convert.insert(0, col_names[n])
            col_n = convert
        else:
            col_n.insert(0, col_names[n])

        col_as_lists.append(col_n)

        # Prints each list into the worksheet.
        worksheet.write_column(self.letters[n] + '1', col_as_lists[n])

    #Formats numerical data as percentage
    percentformat = self.workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
    worksheet.set_column(self.letters[start_data_index] + ':' + self.letters[df_width], None, percentformat)


def add_chart(self, dataframe, tab_name, start_data_index):

    df_width = len(dataframe.columns)

    worksheet = self.workbook.add_worksheet(tab_name)
    self.print_frame(worksheet, dataframe, df_width, start_data_index)

    chart = self.workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
    df_length = (len(dataframe.index))

    for n in range(start_data_index, df_width):

        chart.add_series({
            'name': '=' + tab_name +'!$' + self.letters[n] + '$1',
            'categories': '=' + tab_name +'!$' + self.letters[start_data_index - 1] + '$2:$'+ self.letters[start_data_index - 1] + '$' + str(df_length + 1),
            'values': '=' + tab_name +'!$' + self.letters[n] + '$2:$'+ self.letters[n] + '$' + str(df_length + 1),
            'fill': {'color': '#FFB11E'},
            'data_labels': {'value': True, 'center': True}
        })

    chart.set_title({'name': tab_name})
    chart.set_x_axis({'major_gridlines': {'visible': False}})
    chart.set_y_axis({'major_gridlines': {'visible': False}, 'max': .70})

    worksheet.insert_chart(self.letters[df_width + 2] + '2', chart)

    return

def is_number(self, s):
    """ Function used to help with detecting and converting floats 
    from string to number data types."""
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: The charts that seem "not referenced": Are these charts actually *right*, other than not highlighting their source data when you click on them? Do some of your sheet names have spaces in them and some not?

Comment: Wow, yes, this did seem to be the issue! When I removed the spaces from the sheet names, all of the charts appeared correctly! Regarding your question, yes, other than the reference issue and the data labels appearing as decimals rather than percents, the charts were appearing correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example invocations:

```
test.add_chart(df, 'Df Title', 1)
test.add_chart(df2, 'Df2 Title', 1)
```

suggest that you sometimes had spaces in the names. This results in broken references when you try things like

```
'name': '=' + tab_name +'!$' + self.letters[n] + '$1',
```

which would evaluate to

```
'name': '=Df Title!$A$1',
```

(when `tab_name` equals `'Df Title'` and `n` equals `0`), for example.

You should still be able to have sheet references with spaces, but enclosed in single-quotes, like

```
'name': "='Df Title'!$A$1",
```

so a more robust way to code would be

```
'name': "='" + tab_name +"'!$" + self.letters[n] + '$1',
```

I'm a little surprised that the charts would work at all with the broken sheet references, but I haven't actually tested charts myself, just plain cell formulas that involve sheet names.

Answer (score 3):

@John Y is correct that you aren't quoting the worksheet names correctly in chart range references.

You could avoid this issue, and the hand-rolled conversion from numbers to cell references, by using the chart list syntax rather than the string syntax:

```
chart.add_series({
    'name':       ['Sheet1', 0, col],
    'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 0,   max_row, 0],
    'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, col, max_row, col],
})
```

The snippet is from [this example in the XlsxWriter docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_pandas_chart_line.html).

This applies to a few other places in your code as well. As a general rule in XlsxWriter you can use `row-column` syntax (almost) anywhere you would use `A1` syntax: [Working with Cell Notation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_cell_notation.html).